# Relationship Has Many Through without firstKey

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

is there anyway to get result from hasManythrough relationship without the firstKey?

Right now my result is:

```
 return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Facility', 'App\MerchantBranchFacility', 'id,'facility_id')->select('name');

    {"facilities":[{"name":"AC","id":"13"},{"name":"Wi-Fi","id":"13"}}}
```

I realize that inside hasmanythrough method laravel always do this:

```
  return array_merge($columns, [$this->parent->getTable().'.'.$this->firstKey]);
```

How can i remove "id" without foreach?

Comment: Look at the `$hidden` property on models perhaps?

Comment: nope. i've tried that. because laravel automatic use $this->firstKey instead of column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can set this on a model side, but this:

```
$collection->map(function($item) {
    return array_except($item, 'id');
});
```

Comment: Hi. I've tried yours. Looks promising. but every time i array_except it returns me null. tried plenty of collection seems not getting what i expected

Comment: Working. my mistake at array except $key instead of $item. thanks